# How to stop Excel window from staying on top when macro is running continuously? Application.screenupdating doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a VBA macro that updates a Get HTTP response to a cell every second.

When the macro is running and I switch to another program (Chrome for example), the Excel window (and sometimes along with it the VBA editor) pops up and stays on top after a couple of seconds.

I have seen other posts suggesting the use of `Application.screenupdating = false`, but it doesn't work in my case. I'm using a Mac if that's relevant.

For your info I'm running two subs - first one to get the HTTP response string then call the second sub, and the second sub uses `Application.onTime` to calculate when to execute the first sub again.

I just want the macro to run in the background whilst I work on other tasks.

UPDATE
It seems the Application.onTime command is stealing focus. I tried to run the following sub as a test and it replicated the problem I've been having.

```
Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + 0.01157407 / 1000, "test"
    '0.01157407/1000 = 1 second
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried making Excel's ActiveWindow invisible? You would need to create a trigger to make it visible again when you want but, logically, it shouldn't be able to be on top while it is not visible.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks, but I want to also have the ability to have it show up when I click on the program, so this isn't exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to test your issue as I've never encountered it. And I cannot simply comment on your post with a suggestion. However, using the following Sub should disable most of Excel's updates, events and alerts.

Do note that it will make excel unusable by the user when it is enabled, and therefore needs to be disabled after calculations.

```
Public Sub FastApplication(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .DisplayAlerts = Not opt
        .DisplayStatusBar = Not opt
        .EnableAnimations = Not opt
        .EnableEvents = Not opt
        .ScreenUpdating = Not opt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Perhaps try forcing the window to stay minimized by doing the following; `Application.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMinimized`

Comment: It does minimize the window, but I want to have the ability to have it show and stay when I click on it. Right now it would minimize again right away when I click on it (which is expected).

Comment: Oh I understand your trying to achieve, this is essentially an issue with WPF which you cannot change with VBA. The best course of action is to try and disable focus stealing in Windows. The following thread should get you started; https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3vbzth/turn_off_focus_stealing/

Comment: I did a few tests and found that it is the application.onTime command that seems to be stealing focus...